# Trouble outputting multiple forms in one template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a user settings page with multiple editable and non-editable components. Each editable component has its own form. All of the components are displayed in a table, with the contents coming from a dict on the model. For example:

```
class MyUser(models.AbstractBaseUser):

    def get_settings(self):
        return [
            ('Email Address',
                {'value': self.email, 'editable': True, 'section': 'email', 'form': 'email_form'}
            ), 
            ('Password', 
                {'value': '', 'editable': True, 'section': 'password', 'form': 'password_form'})]
```

I then have a form defined for each item in the settings, such as:

```
class ChangeEmailForm(models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email']
        model = models.MyUser

    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email Address'}))
```

All of the forms are handled by one view, and in that view they are assigned a name, which matches the name in the settings data on the model:

```
def edit_settings_view(request, user):
    if request.POST:
        if 'email_form' in request.POST:
        if email_form.is_valid():
            email_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/settings/')
        else:
            form_errors = email_form.errors
            return render(request, 'settings.html', {'my_user'=user, 'email_form'=email_form, 'form_errors'=form_errors})
    else:
        email_form = ChangeEmailForm(instance=user)
    return render(request, 'settings.html', {'my_user'=user, 'email_form'=email_form})
```

The trouble comes when trying to render the forms in the template. I currently have:

```
{% for key, value in my_user.get_settings %}
    <form action="{% url "edit_profile" %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
            {% for field in value.form %}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" name=value.form>Save</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

However, this just prints the name of the form, e.g 'email_form'. I understand why that's happening, but I don't know how I can get the template to display the form instead. Also, is there a better way of handling the user settings? The code I've shown here is very cut down, but it's basically repeated for each different setting, which isn't very DRY

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in the following way.

First of all, I passed all the forms to the template in a dictionary, like so:

```
forms = {'email_form': email_form, 'password_form': password_form}
return render(request, 'settings.html', {'my_user'=user, 'forms'=forms})
```

And then I got the form from its string name with a custom tag:

```
@register.assignment_tag(name='get_form', takes_context=True)
def get_form(context, form_name):
    forms = context['forms']
    form = forms[form_name]
    return form
```

Obviously if I hadn't changed the way I was passing forms, the tag would have worked with `form = context[form_name]`, so the important part of this answer is the tag.

I still think my code could do with being a bit less repetitive, but at least it works now!